# How to make sure that a password manager is not malicious?

Tags: password-management

Should I disable automatic updates of password management software, such as KeePass? Is there a way to block the software's server from accessing the internet? What if someone in the company adds a malicious feature to the next version of the software?

The question is general, but I'm particularly interested in the Windows version of KeePass.

Comment: You could ask the very same question of any software. You have to have a level of trust at some point.

Comment: the best way to know it's not malicious is to write it yourself, using open-source crypto packages

Comment: @dandavis then the debate moves to whether your home-made solution is secure...

Comment: You could roll your own password manager that is air gapped from the internet, it would be less usable but also more likely to be not malicious

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Disclosure: I work for AgileBits, the makers of 1Password]

### Don't disable automated updates

I'm going to address the easy part of the question first.

> Should I disable automatic updates of password management software.

Unless you have a compelling reason to not update software and systems, one of the best things you can do for your own security is keeping your systems and software up to date.

Most actual compromises of computer systems is via vulnerabilities for which a fix has already been published. These would be prevented if people just kept their systems up to date.

I can't speak for the developers of KeePass, but I am reasonably confident that they do a good job of checking the integrity of updates. I can tell you that with 1Password, we do the following to ensure that an update comes from us.

1. Use strictest TLS settings for both fetching the update and fetching the information about where the update should come from.
2. Use operating system code signing methods so that the operating system ensures that code is signed when run or installed (different on different OS).
3. Use our own code signing check at update time for stricter tests than the OS enforces. (For example, the OS may require that the software be signed by a "known developer". We want to check that it is signed by us.)

I suspect that KeePass and all decent password managers will be doing something similar, though details will vary.

### The harder question

If I may rephrase part of your question:

> What if the developers of a password manager either turn evil, are compelled to be evil, or are compromised by someone with evil intent?

This is the harder question, and it is an important question to ask. For anything that you don't compile yourself on a system that you also built yourself, there is no *absolute* assurance. Sadly we cannot prove in an absolute way that it is *impossible* for evil to get into 1Password without user detection, but we can do things that both make it hard for evil to be inserted and harder still for it to go undetected.

I wrote about this three and a half years ago in [1Password and the Crypto Wars II](https://blog.agilebits.com/2013/09/06/1password-and-the-crypto-wars/)

The major points are that

- The design of our software is well enough documented so that it is possible to independently verify that it does what we say it does for most cases.
- The architecture is such that there are very few places in which a back door be inserted.
- There are enough eyes on the source that if malicious code were inserted in those places, someone would speak up.

There are more points, so please read that article and the discussion in our forums that followed from it. In combination, these provide very good reasons to believe that there is no malicious backdoor in what we build. KeePass can make a similar case even more strongly (given its open source base) but still can't provide absolute proof.

### Weighing risks

You aren't wrong to ask about the possibility of malicious code in your password manager of choice, but also be aware that the same holds for the operating system that you use. It is probably easier for an attacker to compromise your computer than it is to compromise a well-designed password manager. And once your computer is compromised, all bets are off.

And this returns us to automated software updates. Don't let fear of an unlikely threat stop you from taking actions that would defend you from more likely threats. It's fun and informative to talk about the unlikely threats; but when weighing security decisions, we need to look at the security trade-offs as a whole.

Comment: Regarding "checking the integrity of updates" for KeePass: KeePass *doesn't have* an automatic update feature. What KeePass *does* do is check automatically to see whether an update is available. The installer which the user must download for themselves is signed using operating system code signing methods, which the user is encouraged to check. Recently KeePass received some negative press because the check for available updates was not done over TLS. This has been fixed and additionally the update availability information itself is now signed and checked for a valid signature before display.

Comment: (continued) Unfortunately the official download page for KeePass is still not served over HTTPS. The actual download link *from* that page gets the installer over an HTTPS connection to Sourceforge, but not every user will be savvy enough to pay attention to that. On the other hand the user can go directly to the KeePass project page on Sourceforge to protect their session from start to finish. Still, a lot of emphasis is placed on the digital signature on the installer, and the user, rather than making it all automatic.

Comment: I am a bit surprised by this, but I also think I know what the problem is. It is much more expensive to host popular large downloads over HTTPS than HTTP. So it may be because of expenses.

It may also be that they just follow the traditions of ages gone by. Host over insecure channels, but expect people to check signatures and hashes. Though my guess is the cost.

Answer (score 6):

Without certification by an independent body or access to the source control and a real understanding of what you are looking for you can't be absolutely sure that it isn't malicious.

What you can do is to use well established, known password managers like Keepass and keep them updated to patch any vulnerabilities, so you should not disable updates. You could create a rule to ban the application connecting to the internet via something like Windows Firewall or Zonelarm.  Though with so many security researchers, if these well respected products were phoning home, we'd know about it by now.

There's always a small risk a  malicious insider may sneak something untoward in, or a backdoor to serve the government maybe,  it's hard to be sure. It's about balancing the likelihood and risk against the benefits you gain.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that older version of KeePass specifically *have* been certified by an independent body.

Answer (score 4):

Essentially if you download and run software you are "trusting" the author(s) of that software not to be malicious and also to be competent at secure development and also operational security (in the case of automated updates and the like)

Establishing trust in a given set of authors is actually a difficult thing to do, especially if you're an "ordinary" consumer of software and not a large company who might have leverage to request information from vendors.

Some people might suggest that open source answers this, but that's only really true if you (or someone you trust) reviews the code and also handles compilation of the code into a binary form for you to run.

So in practice, your best bet is to assess the software and go with something where you feel comfortable with the source.

On blocking Internet access, that will help if you suspect the software of being malicious but could be difficult to achieve.  Also if you suspect it's malicious, the answer is don't install it.

On automatic updates, those help (in that they let security patches get deployed automatically) but can hurt (if their update server is compromised).

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of like asking how do I know a person close to me isn't malicious. If you trust that person, and come to find they harmed you, then you know they were malicious. You probably aren't going to have all your contacts​ evaluated at a psychologist, and likewise you probably aren't going to statically and dynamically analyze the instructions in your software. Even if you did, what if something slipped by? Perhaps it's conducive to strive for active support, transparency, and good security practices by the developers of your chosen password manager. Try adding so-called two step verification, or two factor authentication, perhaps even hardware tokens in critical "keys to the castle" password protected accounts, if you think extending trust does not have a reasonable or sufficient part to play. After all, this is a relationship, and relationships are about trust.